# Exception "failed to connect to all addresses" in gRpc Unity3D client and ASP.Net core server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, unity-game-engine, grpc

I tested grcp asp.net server with console client and it is working. Sure first problems was with certification, but after install certification on client it start work.

Now I'm testing same server with new client that is Unity3D version 2021.1.2f1. I set project to .NET 4.x like in tutorial. Install plugins grcp for unity. But something go wrong. I feel that may be there is problem with certification, but is there way to install certification for unity client? Unity not support http2, so may be I need configurate this in server and client, or it configurate automatically? May be problem in something another but I can't imagine in what.

I'm getting exception below.

```
RpcException: Status(StatusCode="Unavailable", Detail="failed to connect to all addresses", DebugException="Grpc.Core.Internal.CoreErrorDetailException: {"created":"@1626079380.128000000","description":"Failed to pick subchannel","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\client_channel.cc","file_line":3009,"referenced_errors":[{"created":"@1626079380.128000000","description":"failed to connect to all addresses","file":"..\..\..\src\core\ext\filters\client_channel\lb_policy\pick_first\pick_first.cc","file_line":398,"grpc_status":14}]}")
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ValidateEnd (System.Threading.Tasks.Task task) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1[TResult].GetResult () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
GameManager+<Start>d__1.MoveNext () (at Assets/GameManager.cs:29)
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
System.Runtime.CompilerServices.AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state) (at <695d1cc93cca45069c528c15c9fdd749>:0)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext+WorkRequest.Invoke () (at <9244fb8344e84288877b43b45b29c242>:0)
UnityEngine.UnitySynchronizationContext:ExecuteTasks()
```

Proto file

```
syntax = "proto3";

option csharp_namespace = "GameNetRpc";

package game;

service GameNet {
  rpc SayHello (HelloRequest) returns (HelloReply);
}

message HelloRequest {
  string name = 1;
}

message HelloReply {
  string message = 1;
}
```

Launch setting

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "AspGrpcServer": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": "true",
      "launchBrowser": false,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5000;https://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Client code

```
using GameNetRpc;
using Grpc.Core;
using UnityEngine;

public class GameManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private Channel _channel;
    private async void Start()
    {
        _channel = new Channel("localhost", 5001, ChannelCredentials.Insecure);
        var client = new GameNet.GameNetClient(_channel);
        var reply = await client.SayHelloAsync(new HelloRequest { Name = "Client unity" });
        Debug.Log("Response from server: " + reply.Message);
    }

    private void OnDestroy()
    {
        _channel.ShutdownAsync().Wait();
    }
}
```

Comment: Note the Grpc.Core only supports unity experimentally (=not officially supported). Also, we plan to deprecate Grpc.Core in the future: https://grpc.io/blog/grpc-csharp-future/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I start use MagicOnion and found the solution of error [here](https://github.com/Cysharp/MagicOnion/#support-for-unity-client) https://github.com/Cysharp/MagicOnion/#support-for-unity-client